# Move CSS backgroundImage to a HTML element

Tags: css, razor

I have a template written by someone else, and they have used an image in the CSS as a backgound image like so.

```
.block-title__inner:after {
    background-image: url('../media/bg/11.jpg');
}
```

I am using this template in a CMS and need it to change to a simple img tag so I can change the image used in the backend.

So instead of the HTML being

```
<div class="block-title__inner "></div>
```

It would change to

```
<div class="block-title__inner">
    <img src="../media/bg/11.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Ive searched around but either nothing is out there or Im not using the correct terms, eitherway I cant find anything around how to do this so any help would be great.

Comment: Is the div dynamic sized or static ? can you share more details ?

Comment: have you tried to use inline-styles?

Comment: I dont really want to use inline styles, would rather keep the CSS/HTML in their respective areas unless thats the only way to do it.

Comment: Is jQuery an option? I updated my answer

Comment: I prefer the jquery way to inline styles, Its frustrating ass I dont know much about CSS :S

Comment: Another option is to write an universal script which takes the img src from the img tag and changes the css of the parent. Advantage: you can use it not only in this case

Comment: Well that is my thought, there is quite a few images which have been put in the CSS as background images which is annoying as they all need to be configurable via the CMS.

Comment: Check out my Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cdmp22ay/2/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109022/discussion-between-tony-gayter-and-techtreedev).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer has been edited due to new found information:

The website in question is: headyherps.azurewebsites.net/available/adult/gregory

Instead of using a background-image CSS property as your theme has done by default, you'd like to place an img tag within the parent instead because you consider that the best way to manage the content.

So, Your HTML looks something like this:

```
<div class="block-title__inner section-bg section-bg_second">
    <img src="../media/bg/11.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="bg-inner">
        <!--header elements-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Now in order to get the img to behave in a similar fashion to the background-position property we need to apply some CSS properties to it.

```
.block-title__inner img{
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   top: 0px;
   width: auto;
   height: auto;
   min-width: 100%;
   min-height: 100%; /* optional fail-safe for images that are too short */
}
```

Comment: Yeah I can do whatever I want to the code, its just a template I bought from TF. I just have no idea about CSS which is why I got one from elsewhere, unfortunately all the images are set in CSS which is why I need to move them out :(

Comment: Why not remove the CSS declaring the background image?
Otherwise: consider adding a css important rule: .block-title__inner{background-image: none !important;}

Comment: Yeah I have removed teh css declaration, but I need to have that image in the HTML so it still shows

Comment: This may help, this is the page Im trying to change.

http://headyherps.azurewebsites.net/available/adult/gregory/

As you can see there is a background image in the header, but its defined in teh CSS, I am trying to move the src definition to the HTMl so I can change it in my CMS (using Umbraco)

Comment: I've updated this answer to be more suitable to your question.
Please note: examples of your code and/or a link as well as further descriptions are very important to provide when asking questions.

Comment: Thank you that exactly what I was after, sorry if the question was badly worded, I wasnt quite sure how to put it :)

Comment: @TonyGayter Keep in mind that anwers, that didn't solved your problem like this, but show considerable effort, can also be upvoted (also this answer),as this is common sense on SO :)

Comment: @EoghanTadhg Excellent Approach. +1

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this would work with inline styles.

```
<div style="background-image: url(../media/bg/11.jpg)"></div>
```

You can also use jQuery:

```
$(function(){
        $('.block-title__inner').css("background", "url(../media/bg/11.jpg) ");

    });
```

Don't forget to include it in your `<head>`

Another option ist to write a script that changes the parents style by using the src

https://jsfiddle.net/cdmp22ay/2/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the markup the same as:

```
<div class="block-title__inner"></div>
```

You can get the `img` src from the CSS class attached with jQuery and append the div with an image.

```
var bg = $('.block-title__inner').css('background-image');
bg = bg.replace('url(','').replace(')','');
console.log(bg);
$('.block-title__inner').append('<img id='theImg' src="' + bg + '" />');
```